Integer to Hexadecimal in MIPS Assembly
I'm not sure what's wrong with my algorithm here, it seems like my $t3 register is almost always 9 or less so I just get a ton of 48s in a row.
Here is the code:
.data
prompt: .asciiz "Please enter value: "
ans: .asciiz "Hex: "
#*****************

.text
.globl main
main:


la $a0, prompt
li $v0, 4
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall

move $t2, $v0

la $a0, ans
li $v0, 4
syscall

Loop:

rol $t4, $t2, 4
and $t3, $t4, 0xf

ble $t3, 9, Add
addi $t3, $t3, 55

j Print

Add:

addi $t3, $t3, 48

Print:

li $v0, 1
move $a0, $t3
syscall

beqz $t2, EndLoop

srl $t2, $t2, 4

j Loop

EndLoop:

li $v0, 10
syscall

Any help is greatly appreciated
I honestly don't exactly know what
rol $t4, $t2, 4
and $t3, $t4, 0xf

exactly does but I think this is where the error is. I've messed with it a bit but it still doesn't work.

Does MIPS even have rotate instructions?  That might be a pseudo-instruction for (x<<4) | (x>>(32-4)).  It's intended to rotate left by 4 bits and isolate the low 4 bits (previously the high 4) into $t3.  That gives you a 4-bit integer to turn into a hex digit.  If you're going to use a rotate at all, normally you'd use the same register for source and destination, like x = rol(x, 4) / print_hex( x & 0xf ); as the loop body in a loop that runs 8 times to print all 8 hex digits.

Yeah, this code has a separate srl $t2, $t2, 4.  (Which should be a left shift, since the rotate extract the high bits every time).  The rotate/and could just be be srl $t3, $t2, 28 to go with a loop update of sll $t2, $t2, 4, with a separate loop counter.  (You can't early out when the value becomes zero because those would be trailing zeros, not leading.  Since 16 is a power of 2, we can extract digits in MSD-first printing order, vs. for decimal we can only efficiently get digits in low digit first order.)

There's no need to use a confusing pseudo instruction for this as it can be done with simple shifts and masks — this means you can work out the algorithm in C or Java first, then take it to assembly language.  As it is you have neither a working algorithm nor working assembly code, so suggest to start with the former, a working algorithm, then work on your assembly of same.
